# Firebase: Delete user analytics data - userdeletionRequests:upsert - GDPR

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics

My question is, how can I delete a users analytics data from firebase using "Google User Deletion API" and its method: userdeletionRequests:upsert?  This is important for me to fully fulfill GDPR.

I tried searching for this, but didn't a solution for using it in combination with "NodeJS" and "firebase-cloud-functions".

My biggest problem is, how I get the access, token, this is what I have for now:

```
const accessToken = (await admin.credential.applicationDefault().getAccessToken()).access_token;

return ky.post(constants.googleUserDeletionURL, {
    body: JSON.stringify({
        kind: "analytics#userDeletionRequest",
        id: {
            type: "USER_ID",
            userId: uid,
          },
          propertyId: constants.googleUserDeletionPropertyId,
    }),
    headers: {
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
}).catch((err) => {
    functions.logger.log(`An Error happened trying to delete user-anayltics ${(err as Error).message}`);
});
```

But I always get `An Error happened trying to delete user-anayltics Request failed with status code 403 Forbidden`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after some painful and long days (literally took me like >20 hours), I've figured out how to achieve this request. Here is a step for step guide:

### Step 1 - Needed Dependencies

To send a post-request to google, we need a http-client-library. I've choosen "ky", so we need to install it first with:

```
npm install ky
```

Furthermore, we need to create or OWN oAuth2 token, otherwise the post request will be denied with "error 403". To create our own oAuth token, we need another dependency:

```
npm install @googleapis/docs
```

### Step 2 - Needed Google Property ID

With your request, Google needs to know which property-id / project you are targeting (where it should later delete the user-analytics-data). To get this property-id, we need to log in into GCP via Firebase (not the "real" GCP, the one via Firebase).

For this, go into your "console.firebase.google.com" → Select your project → Analytics Dashboard → "View more in Google Analytics (button at the right corner)"

[image]

Write "property-id" into the search field and then save it somewhere (we need it later)

[image]

### Step 3 - Creating Client-Secret

The third step is to create a service-account, which we will later add into our functions-folder, in order to create our `oAuthClient` (don't worry, you will see what I mean to a later point)

To create your new service.json, log in to google cloud platform via "https://cloud.google.com/" and then follow the pictures:

FIRST:

[image]

SECOND:

[image]

THIRD:

[image]

FOURTH:

[image]

FIFTH

[image]

### Step 4 - Download JSON

After we created our "oAuth-Deleter service-account", we need to manually download the needed JSON, so we can paste it into our functions-folder.

For this, select "oauth-deleter@your-domain.iam.gserviceaccount.com" under "Service Account"

[image]

Then click on "Keys" and "Add key", which will automagically download you a service-json (SELECT **Key type** → JSON → Create).

[image]

[image]

### Step 5 - Paste JSON file into your functions-folder

To loosen up the mood a bit, here is an easy step. Paste the downloaded JSON-File into your functions-folder.

[image]

### Step 6 - Grant Access to our new created oAuth-Delelter-Account

Creating the service-account and giving it access in the normal GCP is not enough for Google, so we also have to give it access in our Firebase project. For this, go back into your "GCP via Firebase (see Step 2)" → Click on Setting → "User Access for Account" → Click on the "plus"

[image]

Then click on "Add user" and write the email we copied before into the email field (the email from Step 3, Picture FOURTH "Service-Account ID). In our case, it is "oAuth-Deleter@your-domain.iam.gserviceaccount.com". Furthermore, it needs admin-access:

[image]

### Step 6 - The code

Now, after these million unnecessary but necessary steps, we get to the final part. THE DAMN CODE. I've written this in typescript with "compilerOptions" → "module": "esnext", "target": "esnext". But I am sure that you are smart enough to change the code after completing this many steps :)

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";
import functions from "firebase-functions";
import ky from "ky";
import docs from "@googleapis/docs";
import { UserRecord } from "firebase-functions/v1/auth";

export const dbUserOnDeleted = functions.
   .auth
   .user()
   .onDelete((user) => doOnDeletedUser(user))

    ----------------------------

export asnc function doOnDeletedUser/user: UserRecord) {
   try {
       const googleDeletionURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/userDeletion/userDeletionRequests:upsert"
       
       // Step 1: Paste propertyID: (See Step 2)
       const copiedPropertyID = "12345678"

       // Step 2: Create oAuthClient
       const oAuthClient = new docs.auth.GoogleAuth({
           keyFile: "NAME-OF-THE-FILE-YOU-COPIED-INTO-YOUR-FUNCTIONS-FOLDER",
           scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.user.deletion"]
       });

       // Step 3: Get user uid you want to delete from user-analytics
       const uid = user.uid

      // Step 4: Generate access token 
      // (this is the reason why we needed the 5 steps before this)
      // yup, a single line of code
      const accessToken = await oAuthClient.getAccessToken() as string;

      // Step 5: Make the request to google and delete the user
      return ky.post(googleDeletionURL, {
          body: JSON.stringify({
              kind: "analytics#userDeletionRequest",
              id: {
                 type: "USER_ID",
                 userid: uid
              },
              propertyId: copiedPropertyID
          }),
          headers: {
              "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
          }
      });

   } catch (err) {
     functions.logger.error(`Something bad happened, ${(err as Error).message)`
   }
}
```

### Afterthoughts

This was and probably will be my longest post at stack overflow forever. I have to say that it was a pain in the a** to get this thing to working. The amount of work and setup that is needed to simply delete a data from one endpoint is just ridiculous. Google, please fix.